nested virtualization, libvirt: network usually not working
So, I have a VPS where hardware nested virtualization is enabled, and I am trying to use this nested virtualization. The VPS runs Debian 12 and has 16 Gb of RAM.
I installed libvirt/virt-manager/etc and downloaded the "nocloud" and "genericcloud" images from https://cdimage.debian.org/images/cloud/ . The description says that the "nocloud" image should allow passwordless root login but unfortunately it does not. I run things as root (this is a test setup) but I di chown all qcow images to "libvirt-qemu".
I use the following command line:
# virt-install --name test-cloud-vnc --os-variant debian11 --ram 8192 --disk debian-12-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=10,format=qcow2 --hvm --import
--noautoconsole --network default --graphics vnc,port=-1,listen=0.0.0.0

(Or the same for the nocloud image)
The nocloud image sometimes, rarely, gets a DHCP lease (visible in virsh net-dhcp-leases-default) and then responds to pings. But usually the nocloud image, and always the cloud image (but this might just be by random numbers), don't gety a DHCP lease and cannot be pinged. This means that my attempt to set up cloud-init by an ad hoc webserver (as per https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/qemu.html ) never got tested, because the cloud-init image can't access the network to start with.
dmesg output for the time:
[71382.495314] audit: type=1400 audit(1732157273.151:173): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-3ca46e41-5cca-40b0-a5cd-d7d7e60de326" pid=30675 c
omm="apparmor_parser"
[71382.855419] audit: type=1400 audit(1732157273.511:174): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-3ca46e41-5cca-40b0-a5cd-d7d7e60de326" pid=3067
8 comm="apparmor_parser"
[71383.228796] audit: type=1400 audit(1732157273.883:175): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-3ca46e41-5cca-40b0-a5cd-d7d7e60de326" pid=3068
2 comm="apparmor_parser"
[71383.626483] audit: type=1400 audit(1732157274.279:176): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-3ca46
e41-5cca-40b0-a5cd-d7d7e60de326" pid=30686 comm="apparmor_parser"
[71383.664542] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
[71383.667108] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
[71383.671212] device vnet0 entered promiscuous mode
[71383.674775] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
[71383.677431] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered listening state
[71384.077738] audit: type=1400 audit(1732157274.731:177): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-3ca46e41-5cca-40b0-a5cd-d7d7e60de326" pid=3069
7 comm="apparmor_parser"
[71385.702614] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered learning state
[71387.718555] virbr0: port 1(vnet0) entered forwarding state
[71387.720995] virbr0: topology change detected, propagating

I did try --network default,model=e1000 - no change. I do successfully see the guest console when I connect to the VPS by VNC. Unfortunately, I don't have a password to log in with, so I can't even try to see whether it sees any network adapter.
I tried to boot the GRML ISO ( https://grml.org/ ) using the following command:
# virt-install --name test-cloud-vnc --os-variant debian11 --ram 8192 --disk debian-12-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio,size=10,format=qcow2 --hvm --import
--noautoconsole --network default --cdrom grml64-full_2024.02.iso --boot cdrom  --graphics vnc,port=-1,listen=0.0.0.0

Unfortunately, the GRML boot hangs shortly after starting, apparently while trying to load the initrd. So I can't poke around in the guest in this way, either.
Advice about debugging this would be highly appreciated.
